# Case Statements in LINQ query - AnonymousType to String?

Tags: asp.net, linq, visual-studio-2010

I basically have the following:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString, string clientNo, int status = -1)
{
    var statusLst = new List<string>();
    var statusNoQry = from b in db.Briefs
                      orderby b.Status
                      select new  
                      {
                          status = (
                            b.Status == 0 ? "Requested" :
                            b.Status == 1 ? "In Progress" :
                            "Undefined"
                            )
                      };
    statusLst.AddRange(statusNoQry.Distinct()); <<--- ERROR HERE
    ViewBag.status = new SelectList(statusLst);

    var ClientNoLst = new List<string>();
    var ClientNoQry = from b in db.Briefs
                      orderby b.Client_No_
                      where b.Client_Type == 0 
                      select b.Client_No_;
    ClientNoLst.AddRange(ClientNoQry.Distinct());
    ViewBag.clientNo = new SelectList(ClientNoLst);

    var briefs = from b in db.Briefs
                 select b;

    Session["searchString"] = searchString;
    Session["clientNo"] = clientNo;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        briefs = briefs.Where(s => s.Client_No_.Contains(searchString) || s.Name.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if ((status > -1) && (status < 10))
    {
        briefs = briefs.Where(y => y.Status == status);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientNo))
        return View(briefs);
    else
        return View(briefs.Where(x => x.Client_No_ == clientNo));
}
```

However, I receive the following area:

```
Error   7   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'
```

Status is of type int but I would like to cast it to string for my dropdownlist. I'm quite new to all this, what is the appropriate way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is returning an anonymous type:

```
select new  
{
    status = (
    b.Status == 0 ? "Requested" :
    b.Status == 1 ? "In Progress" :
    "Undefined"
    )
};
```

You need to return a set of strings though. The error is telling you exactly what the problem is.

```
select 
    (b.Status == 0 ? "Requested" :
    b.Status == 1 ? "In Progress" :
    "Undefined");
```

Edit - You didn't post the rest of the method, but from you have your also not disposing your context object, which can cause problems. Normally you wrap this in a `using` clause.

Comment: Hi asawyer, I have now posted the whole method. But what you suggested did the trick.